# Independent but not identically distributed

Tags: statistics, machine-learning, probability, probability-theory

Let X1, X2,...,Xn be discrete random variables. I'm looking for a way to prove the random variables are independent but not identically distributed.

Can anyone suggest some ideas ?

Comment: This isn't about programming; try http://stats.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

Independence test is simple, and works for any distributions, X and Y are independent iff

P(X,Y)=P(X)P(Y)

testing whether they come from different distributions requires more advanced statistical tests - for example test whether the differences between these distributions are statistically significant using [t-test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test)

Both can be easily tested using R statistical software or any other similar tool (Matlab, Octave)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm not sure about testing the 'identical distribution' (ID) part. Can you please explain that ?